# Minimum number of straight lines needed to cover $n$ points

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we are given a set of $n$ points in the euclidean plane , they are distributed arbitarily (not in general position).
what is the minimum number of lines in the plane needed to cover them all?

Comment: your answer is the maximum, look the paper by Grantson "covering a set of points with a minimum number of lines"        eurocg.org/06/delaunay.tem.uoc.gr/~mkaravel/ewcg06/papers/35.pdf

Answer (score -1):

The minimum number of lines is ${n\choose 2}-{k\choose 2}$ where n is the number of points while $k$ is number of points which are collinear if any.

Comment: ok.but how to determine number of collinear points between the n points?

Comment: I have generalized  it. It should be given .we cant find it like that. Either the figure should be given or the points collinear from n .points